# How shear-strain is related to diagonals?

Tags: material-science, elasticity, stress-strain

In two dimension the shear strain causes deformation of diagonals, But how the diagonals are deformed (means which stress is acting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume the framework of linear elasticity (small strains, small angular changes) because whole chapters/books could be written about large deformations. In any case, thoroughly understanding the former is crucial to studying the latter.

We can visually represent shear (of a square differential element) in a few different ways (depending on which side or point of the element we hold constant):

[image]
[image]
[image]

(Images from [my site](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/generalized%20Hooke%27s%20Law.htm).)

Here, the deformations are $\boldsymbol{u}$, and the side lengths are $\boldsymbol{x}$. Since Nature doesn't care which way we draw a conceptual element, we reconcile the differences by defining the (*tensorial*) shear $\varepsilon_{12}$ as

$$\varepsilon_{12}\equiv\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{u_1}}{\boldsymbol{x_2}}+\frac{\boldsymbol{u_2}}{\boldsymbol{x_1}}\right).$$

By trigonometry and the small-angle assumptions ($\sin\theta\approx\theta$, $\tan\theta\approx\theta$), we find that the relative change in the diagonal is the same. We also find that the decrease in the corner angle is twice this, or

$$\gamma=\frac{\boldsymbol{u_1}}{\boldsymbol{x_2}}+\frac{\boldsymbol{u_2}}{\boldsymbol{x_1}},$$

where $\gamma$ is called the *engineering* shear strain.

Answer (score 1):

> Is shear strain related to change in diagonal

If I understand correctly what you are asking, then yes, in the sense that pure shear loading on the cube results in both shear stress and strain as well as normal stress and strain along the diagonals of the cube.

The figure below shows one side of a cube where the cube is subjected to pure external shear loading. The resulting shear strain is exaggerated for emphasis.

Note that the applied shear stresses result in compressive and tensile normal stresses, called principle stresses, along the diagonals. Those stresses result in compressive and tensile strain along the diagonals.

This a special case of the general 2D case given by the equation

$$\sigma_{a}, \sigma_{b}=\frac{\sigma_{x}+\sigma_{y}}{2}\pm\sqrt {\frac{\sigma_{x}-\sigma_{y}}{2}+\tau_{xy}^{2}}$$

Where $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$ are the principle stress and where the applied normal stresses are $\sigma_{x}$ and $\sigma_{y}$. When the applied normal stresses are zero, then the principle stresses become

$$\sigma_{a}, \sigma_{b}=\pm \tau_{xy}$$

And the shear strains along the diagonals are

Tensile strain: $\epsilon =+\frac{\sigma_a}{E}$

Compressive strain: $\epsilon =-\frac{\sigma_b}{E}$

Hope this helps.

[image]